Is the convention of -1^2 being equal to 1 universal? What is its mathematical justification?
The common convention tells us that –1²=–1 since, as explained in the post below, "The exponent binds first."
Incredibly basic notation question: Is $-1^2$ 1 or -1? How about $-x^2$ where $x$ is $1$?
However, this explanation, whilst undoubtedly correct with regard to the convention, fails to explain the logic behind it. The exponent binds first, but it binds to what? The number, of course. And a number can be positive or negative. This interpretation, therefore, assumes essentially that negative numbers do not exist, with the single exception of –1.
As the author of the post above stated, "−1 is a single thing (a negative number)." It is curious that the convention would tell us to intpret –5², for example, as meaning −1 × 5² instead of just what it implies, –5 × –5.
Is this convention universal? And if so, is there a non-arbitrary (i.e. mathematical) justification for it? Thank you.

Exponents take priority, but to be clear you could use parentheses:  $-(1)^2$ vs. $(-1)^2$

This is just bad ambiguous notation and you should avoid it. I can't imagine a situation where it would be necessary, anyway.

$-1^2$ is not $1,$ $(-1)^2$ is $1.$

"This interpretation, therefore, assumes essentially that negative numbers do not exist, with the single exception of –1.": No. In $-1^2$, "the number" (to which the exponent binds) is $1$. "intpret –5² [...] instead of just what it implies, –5 × –5." No. It "implies" what is written, following the priority rule you recalled, i.e. $-(5^2)$.

Negative "one-squared" is $-1$. And "negative-one" squared is $1$. The standard notation is to assume that $-1^2$ means negative (one-squared) or $-1$.

It doesn't bind to the number. It bind's to the symbol before it's interpreted as a number, because it's a matter of syntax, not of semantics.

@J.W.Tanner - Would you not rather write the first parenthesized version as $-(1^2)$?

Yes, @JonathanZ, I would

But it's the ideal first comment for this question, and you can't edit it now. :-(

I would expect the notation to be consistent with $-xy$ so $-x^2=-xx$.

I note that your title and post seem to disagree with each other.

The operation of subtraction ($-$) takes two arguments, so, "$-x$" is really an abbreviation of $0 - x$. In particular, "$-1$" is an abbreviation of $0 - 1$ and $-1^2$ is an abbreviation of $0 - 1^2 = 0 - 1$.

The only thing that I find interesting about this is that it's actually the "-" in "-1" that's ambiguous. We don't know if it means "take the negative of the number 1", or if it's part of the way we write the number that is the negative of 1.
Written by itself, we humans don't fuss over the difference, as both interpretations lead to the same number in the end. Though if we were parsing arithmetical expressions (into trees) with a computer program, note that the different interpretations correspond to different trees, one with two nodes and one with just one node. Also, lots of calculators used to have two different keys, one for "minus" and one for "change sign". (As I'm a relic who still uses RPN, I have no idea what the general practice is nowadays.)
Anyways, adding the superscript "${}^2$" exposes the ambiguity, and, since we're not computers, the intelligent person removes the ambiguity with parentheses instead of wasting time debating it.

I've seen this in MS Excel. Not only is $-1^2$ rendered as $+1$, but expressions that would seem to force exponentiation to get priority like $-1^{2.5}$ give errors instead. So does $-1^{2/3}$ despite the form being suitable for root extraction ($(-1)^{2/3}=\sqrt[3]{(-1)^2}=1$).
Apparently the unary negative sign is given priority over all binary operations including exponentiation (there is no problem when we write $=0-1^2$ in MS Excel, making the minus sign a binary subtraction). Using explicit parentheses is simply the safest option.

You’re right; MS Excel renders $−1^2$ as $1$

Wow, a brand-new reason (added to the many old ones) to hate MS products.

The way I think about it is as follows. Given any number $x$, there is a unique number $y$ with the property that $x+y=0.$ "The additive inverse of $x$" or "the opposite of $x$" are the most common names for $y.$ For simplicity, I will use the latter.
One can prove that for any $x,$ $-x=(-1)\cdot x,$ for example by showing that $x+(-1)\cdot x=0.$ This doesn't mean we'd necessarily define $-x$ that way. We can use this fact to show very readily that for any numbers $x$ and $y,$ $$(-x)\cdot y=-(x\cdot y),$$ so there is no risk of equivocation when we write $-x\cdot y,$ instead.
Knowing that opposition (or as it's sometimes known, "negation") is related to and interacts with multiplication in these ways, we can conclude that it happens at the same "stage" of the GEMA (grouping, exponentiation, multiplication, addition) "order of operations" as multiplication does. Thus, since exponentiation "happens first" in $-5^2,$ then we interpret it to mean "the opposite of the square of five," which is the opposite of twenty-five, which is the negative number that's $25$ from $0,$ a.k.a. "negative twenty-five."
Ultimately, this convention (like other GEMA conventions such as PEMDAS or BODMAS) was just chosen for convenience in order to cut down on the need to write every single grouping symbol that we would otherwise need in order to make sense of multi-operational expressions.

Well while you may think that the negative sign is "bound" to the number, think of it as every number is positive, but instead of adding the positive number you subtract it. E.g $-5^2$ is the same as $-(+5^2)$ or any negative number as $-(+x)$. $-1^2$ does not imply (-1) * (-1) as you say it does. So to summarize, the sign is not bound to the number.
Proof:
If $-5^2$ would imply $(-5)(-5)$ then it would lead to groundbreaking issues. Lets say you wanted to subtract 25 from 100:
$$\rightarrow 100 -25$$
25 is equal to $5^2$. Then this expression would become.
$$100 - 5^2$$
But according to your statement $-5^2 = (-5)(-5) = 25$. Therefore the expression becomes:
$$100 + 25 = 125$$
This does not work as $100 - 25  = 75\neq 125$
Hence proving why
$$\boxed{-5^2 = -(5)(5) = -25}$$
